# how to translate img from its position on button click?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to translate my image from it position to **some pixel** for some time (example 5 sec).on button click
could you please suggest how to do this ? I am using `translateX` but not working. how to give time here ?

```
    document.querySelector("#img").style.translateX = "-100px";
```

here is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Static Template</title>
    <style>
      .abc {
        width: 400px;
        height: 400px;
        background-color: red;
      }
      .img {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0vh;
        left: 0;
        content: " ";
        background-image: url("./a.png");
        background-size: 100% 100%;
        width: 100%;
        height: 50vh;
        opacity: 0.4;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="abc">
      <img src="./a.png" class="img" id="img" />
      hello
    </div>

    <button onclick="pre()">Pre</button>
    <button onclick="next()">Next</button>
    <script>
      function next() {
        document.querySelector("#img").style.translateX = "-100px";
      }

      function pre() {
        document.querySelector("#img").style.translateX = "100px";
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/ancient-cookies-ewepg?file=/index.html:0-1056

Answer (score 0):

Specify `transition-duration` in the style of image.

The correct way to specify translate is:

`document.querySelector("#img").style.transform = "translateX(100px)";`

Here's the code snippet:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Static Template</title>
    <style>
      .abc {
        width: 400px;
        height: 400px;
        background-color: red;
      }
      .img {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0vh;
        left: 0;
        content: " ";
        background-color: green;
        background-image: url("./a.png");
        background-size: 100% 100%;
        width: 100%;
        height: 50vh;
        opacity: 0.4;
        transition-duration: 2s;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="abc">
      <img src="./a.png" class="img" id="img" />
      hello
    </div>

    <button onclick="pre()">Pre</button>
    <button onclick="next()">Next</button>
    <script>
      let translateNextCount = 1;
      function next() {
        document.querySelector("#img").style.transform = `translateX(${translateNextCount * 100}px)`;
        translateNextCount++;
      }

      function pre() {
        document.querySelector("#img").style.transform = "translateX(-100px)";
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: first time it is working ...? why it is not working second time ?

Comment: i press next button first time it moves .. but when i again press next button it does not move why ?

Comment: Because a fixed value of `100px` is passed to `translateX`.
You can add a variable to keep track of the number of times `next` button was clicked and then use it this way: `document.querySelector("#img").style.transform = translateX(${translateNextCount * 100}px);`

Modified the code snippet for `next` button.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const img = document.querySelector("#img");
      function next() {
        img.classList.remove("horizTranslateReverse");
        img.classList.add("horizTranslate");
      }

      function pre() {
        img.classList.remove("horizTranslate");
        img.classList.add("horizTranslateReverse");
      }
```

```css
.abc {
        width: 400px;
        height: 400px;
        background-color: red;
      }
      .img {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0vh;
        left: 0;
        content: " ";
        background-image: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1622515658990-017acdeeade3?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=282&q=80 282w");
        background-size: 100% 100%;
        width: 50%;
        height: 50vh;
        opacity: 0.4;
        -webkit-transition: 3s;
        -moz-transition: 3s;
        -ms-transition: 3s;
        -o-transition: 3s;
        transition: 3s;
      }

      .img.horizTranslate {
        margin-left: 50% !important;
      }
      .img.horizTranslateReverse {
        margin-left: 0% !important;
      }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Static Template</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="abc">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1622515658990-017acdeeade3?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=282&q=80 282w" class="img" id="img" />
      hello
    </div>

    <button onclick="pre()">Pre</button>
    <button onclick="next()">Next</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: thnaks for answer it is working only first time not second time. i will to transpate it's position always